# Paint new things on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Ok, so I have a JPanel with the *paintComponent* method overrided.

it's simple, looks like this:

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

   public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent (g);
      g.fillOval (0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight ());
   }
}
```

Now, I add this JPanel as an attribute to another JPanel class, like:

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel {

   Panel1 panel;

   public Panel2 (Panel1 panel) {
      this.panel = panel;
   }

   protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent (g);
      panel.paint (g); //This isn't working.
//          panel.paintComponent (g); //Tried this too

      g.drawOval (100, 100, getWidth () - 200, getHeight () - 200);
   }
}
```

What I want is Panel2 to be painted exactly the same as Panel1 (without hard-coding it) and maybe add other stuff (like a triangle or sth, I don't know).

Is this even possible? I looked into it but didn't find any way to do it. Thanks in advance for your help!!

The **MAIN** in case it helps:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
      frame.setSize (500, 500);

      frame.add (new Panel2 (new Panel1 ()));

      frame.setVisible (true);
   }
}
```

EDIT: just in case, I don't want to do it with inheritance; that's why I add it as an attribute, but if there is other way just let me now.

Comment: You could add a Panel1 as a child of Panel2.

Comment: Yes, but as I said I need to avoid inheritance on this example. (It is an academic example and inheritance wouldn't do what we need it to do).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  BTW - there are special tricks for displaying components that have not yet been 'realized' on-screen, which might be the problem here.

Comment: This is the MCVE, my project is a lot bigger; what kind of "tricks" could that be? I'm not an expert, just starting to study this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make `paintComponent` of `Panel1` public and then call it in `paintComponent` of `Panel2`:

```
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    panel1.paintComponent(g);
}
```

You could also create a method inside your `Panel1` class that handles the painting for you

```
public void yourPainting(Graphics g){
    //whatever you want to paint
}
```

and then call this method in the `paintComponent` methods of both your `Panel1` and your `Panel2`

Comment: Tried that and didn't work, it just does nothing =( (modified the code, in case you can see something odd there)

Comment: are you shure you tried everything I suggested? I just tried it out myself and it worked just fine.

Comment: I did. See in the _new_ code I posted before how I do declare paintComponent public, and try to use paintComponent on the Panel2.paintComponent. Could you see the code? Because I'm starting to think that it might be something else (a weird initialization or something, I don't know).

Comment: I just added another suggestion you could try out. And by the way, you want to add your panel to the frame like this: frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

Comment: Tried that too. I know it SHOULD work, but I don't know why it doesn't

Comment: I just tried your exact code and it works just like it should.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't add panel1 to any frame and therefore panel1 doesn't have a size so it tries to fill a oval with 0 height and 0 width.

Comment: Oh god, didn't notice that! Thanks a lot, just tried modifying it and it works =D

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work the way seen in the question is that `Panel1` has a size of 0x0.  To get a sensible size, return a size from `getPreferredSize()`, then set the panel size to the preferred size.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintUnrealized {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Paint Unrealized Component");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(new Panel2(new Panel1()));
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    Panel1 panel;

    public Panel2(Panel1 panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        panel.paintComponent(g); // This works

        int pad = 25;
        g.drawOval(pad, pad, getWidth()-(2*pad), getHeight()-(2*pad));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel {
    private Panel1 panel1;

    public Panel2 (Panel1 panel) {
        this.panel1 = panel;
    }

    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
         panel1.paint(g);
    }  
}
```

I believe that should work

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work (didn't do anything).

Comment: Just modified the code on the post to add everything, could you please see if we have the same?